# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()

Tags: web-services, maven, tomcat, amazon-ec2, jersey

I'm trying create a Restful Web Service using Jersey with Maven and Tomcat. When I do execute my webservice, does throws some exceptions and doesn't work.

It runs in the localhost:8080 perfectly but I am running the same code in linux EC2 instance then the error exists.

I searched before asking this question but I didn't find any solution regarding this even though we have so many questions on this.

Please help me.

Below are the code details:

**Service:**

```
    package com.example.subscribe;

    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.example.subscribe.Subscribe;
    import com.example.subscribe.SubscribeDao;
    import com.example.subscribe.SubscribeDaoImpl;

    @Path("/subscribe")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class test {

        @POST
        public Response subscribeEmail(Subscribe details) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            String result, output;

            SubscribeDao dao = new SubscribeDaoImpl();
            result = dao.saveDetails(details.email, details.subscriptionDate);
            output = gson.toJson(result);
            return Response.ok().entity(output).build();

        }

    }
```

**Web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Example</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <!-- Register resources and providers -->
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

         <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.subscribe</param-value>
        </init-param>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.careers.CORSFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.1</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.76</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.76</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

**Exception:**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If you need still anymore information I am ready to give.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I notice that jersey-server dependency is at 1.9, while all other jersey dependencies are at 1.19.1. Is this intentional? If not it's probably worth updating it - I doubt it will solve the issue at hand however.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me.

Comment: I have the same issue. Works locally on Win7 and Oracle JDK 8 and Tomcat 8.5.15 but not on AWS Linux with JDK 8.0u111 and Tomcat 8.0.39